# rho command is failing with invalid auth error

Tags: rhel, command, ansible

I am trying to use `rho` command for my localhost on rhel7.6. System is subscribed to redhat under developer subscription. Here are details

```
[root@redhat7-1 ~]# rho profile list
Please enter your rho vault password:
No profiles exist yet.
[root@redhat7-1 ~]# rho auth list
Please enter your rho vault password:
No credentials exist yet.
[root@redhat7-1 ~]# rho auth add --name roothost1 --username root --sshkeyfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Please enter your rho vault password:
Auth "roothost1" was added
[root@redhat7-1 ~]# rho profile add --name mynetwork --hosts 192.168.56.107 --auth roothost1  # 192.168.56.107  is my localhost ip
Please enter your rho vault password:
Profile "mynetwork" was added
[root@redhat7-1 ~]# rho scan --profile mynetwork --reportfile ./mynetwork_scan.csv
Please enter your rho vault password:
Connection discovery will be perform with the following auth credentials: roothost1
Note: Any ssh-agent connection setup for a target host will be used as a fallback if it exists.

Attempting connection discovery to 1 systems with auth "roothost1" using a timeout of 5 minutes.
All auths are invalid for this profile
[root@redhat7-1 ~]# rho profile list
Please enter your rho vault password:
[
    {
        "auth": [
            {
                "id": "8663a7cb-31bf-4644-9631-d8bd0c8df900",
                "name": "roothost1"
            }
        ],
        "hosts": [
            "192.168.56.107"
        ],
        "name": "mynetwork",
        "ssh_port": "22"
    }
]
[root@redhat7-1 ~]# rho auth list
Please enter your rho vault password:
[
    {
        "id": "8663a7cb-31bf-4644-9631-d8bd0c8df900",
        "name": "roothost1",
        "password": null,
        "ssh_key_file": "/root/.ssh/id_rsa",
        "sudo_password": null,
        "username": "root"
    }
]
[root@redhat7-1 ~]# ssh "192.168.56.107"
Last login: Wed Sep 18 13:50:07 2019 from 192.168.56.107
[root@redhat7-1 ~]# logout
Connection to 192.168.56.107 closed.
[root@redhat7-1 ~]#
```

Is there any other way we have to map auths to specific hosts or we have to define any other mandatory options in any of the rho command? I can't figure it out from man page or any docs.

Comment: I’m pretty familiar with RHEL administration but I haven’t encountered the rho command; would you mind adding a link to the docs you’ve consulted?

Comment: I am following this [document](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1286193) and [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rho) page.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Rho version  "0.0.34" and ansible version 2.8. There is a issue with the python source code of rho. In the file `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rho/host_discovery.py` on line no 53. It should be `CHANGED` instead of `SUCCESS`.